# Full match regex for URI

Tags: regex, nginx-log

what is full match regex(python) to find URI only from nginx logs?

```
00.00.00.00 - - [23/Mar/2020:16:23:04 +0000] "GET /foo/bar/uri.js?id=123 HTTP/1.1" 200 19165 "https://nginx.com/foo/bar" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "00.00.00.00" 0.000

00.00.00.00 - - [23/Mar/2020:16:23:04 +0000] "GET /foo/bar/uri HTTP/1.1" 200 19165 "https://nginx.com/foo/bar" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "00.00.00.00" 0.000

00.00.00.00 - - [23/Mar/2020:16:23:04 +0000] "GET /foo/bar/uri.png HTTP/1.1" 200 19165 "https://nginx.com/foo/bar" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "00.00.00.00" 0.000
```

full match regex should give below

```
/foo/bar/uri.js?id=123
/foo/bar/uri
/foo/bar/uri.png
```

example for full match regex: https://regex101.com/r/kEOx1U/3

Comment: Maybe: https://regex101.com/r/AHVPtO/1

Comment: @MDR URI not matching for full match...
example for full match that I am looking https://regex101.com/r/kEOx1U/3

Comment: Viveksai, your regex101 filters on IP-addresses; what exactly are you looking for ?

Comment: thanks @BAerts yes

Answer (score 0):

The regex to match that URIs is the following ([click here](https://regex101.com/r/AHVPtO/4)):

```
(?<=GET )([^ ]*)
```

Clearly, if you want to not only match, but also extract, which means deleting all the rest, you have match it too ([click here](https://regex101.com/r/AHVPtO/3)):

```
.*(?<=GET )([^ ]*).*
```

and use `$1` in the substitution (in Perl; if you need Python, then use `\1`).

Comment: Because you've put a newline at the end of the regex, @VIVEKSAIRAMAGIRI.

Comment: It **is** updated. Your link in the comment points to a wrong regex, @VIVEKSAIRAMAGIRI. Mine works.

Comment: it has groups..but I am only looking for full match

Comment: I am looking for full match example https://regex101.com/r/kEOx1U/3

Comment: @VIVEKSAIRAMAGIRI, clarify in the question what you want.

Comment: full match for uri... not with groups

Comment: @VIVEKSAIRAMAGIRI, click on the two links in my answer.